# Getting ApplicationExecutionState of a Metro Application

Tags: process, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I need to find the currently active metro application.
Windows 8 Task Manager allows you to see the status of the Application as "Suspended" in case the given metro app is in the background.

Is there an API to find the state.

Comment: Please describe the problem you're trying to solve, where you think knowing the execution state is the solution. This information is intentionally not exposed to applications since applications are supposed to be isolated from each other.

Comment: I have a screen capture setup where i want to do selective capture for selected applications (when they are in the foreground). i can get a list of all currently running metro apps but even when they are in the background i have no way to tell the state.
Looking at Task Manager it seems that when the Metro apps go to background the process state is "suspended".
I could use this to distinguish active apps from non active ones. also since active metro apps are alway on top so i dont need to worry about the "z" order of things.

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to do the screen capture either, by the way.  And there could be multiple apps NOT in suspended mode, since suspension doesn't happen immediately.

Comment: So you don't really care who is suspended or not. You merely care about which application is active. Try `GetForegroundWindow`.